# Particular Solution to Second Order Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

How would make a "template" to find the $y_p$ of this equation?

$y''+9y = -6\sec 3t$

I'm not that good with trigonometric functions, but I'm pretty sure we have to do something to make it fit the $\,A \sin t + B \cos t\,$ template

Comment: I voted to close this question, as it is very similar to the other one, and the same way of solving the differential equation works.